# Jquery Input field when user finishes making changes

Tags: jquery, input

I am wondering if their is a way to get what the user entered into an input field once they have click on another field(are done input into that field).  I tried `.change`, but that works for every letter the user inputs.  Is their a way for when the user is done entering text into the input field(clicks on another field)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `.blur()` for that.